# How to add a currency sign in a numericinput

Tags: r, shiny

Is there a way to have a £ sign inside a numeric input box? So that when someone enters a number it is automatically in currency format. if anyone has a solution or can point me in the right direction much appreciated.

Have tried to look for examples online, have only found one thing that uses the paste function but that was for a valueBox function which I have tried and failed to incorporate into this problem.

```
library(shiny)

    ui <- fluidPage(
      fluidRow(
          numericInput("Selectcost", "Enter the cost", value = "", step= 0.01, min= 0, max= 50)
    ))

    server <- function(input, output) {
    }


    shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An option could be to use the `shinyWidgets` package :

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    shinyWidgets::numericInputIcon("Selectcost", 
                                   "Enter the cost", 
                                   value = "", 
                                   step= 0.01, 
                                   min= 0, 
                                   max= 50, 
                                   icon = list(NULL, icon("pound-sign")))
  ))

server <- function(input, output) {
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The `shinyWidgets` package has a great new function (added as of version 0.5.4, also a disclaimer, I added it via a pull request), autonumericInput that will allow you to do just this.  It is based on the javascript library autonumeric.  There are a lot of options to the function, but the documentation is extensive and for simple uses most can be ignored.

What you are trying to do can be accomplished as follows:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  h1("Autonumeric Input Example"),
  shinyWidgets::autonumericInput(
    inputId = "cost", 
    label = "Enter the cost", 
    value = 100, 
    currencySymbol = "£",
    currencySymbolPlacement = "p",
    decimalPlaces = 2
  ),
  verbatimTextOutput("res1")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$res1 <- renderText(input$cost)
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

which results in:

[sample output from the above code chunk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kP5iu.png)

Hopefully this is useful!

Comment: back-sapce does not work properly with autonumericInput